# How to return the same viewController multiple times in swift(iOS) in a single run of the program?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit

I am writing a program using SpriteKit and UIKit.

I have two view controller in my program, first for main page and second for GameViewController (which includes GameScene). I have added a back button to the GameViewController which goes to main page (MainPageViewController). Everything works fine so far.

In my first page, when I wanted to go back again to GameViewController, program crashes and the following error is given:

> GitarTelleri[959:47801] 15:21:39.405 ERROR:
>   AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1743: _Connect: required condition is false:
>   !destNodeMixerConns.empty() && !isDestNodeConnectedToIONode 2016-09-19
>   15:21:39.413 GitarTelleri[959:47801] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required
>   condition is false: !destNodeMixerConns.empty() &&
>   !isDestNodeConnectedToIONode'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104250d85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00000001061d2deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x0000000104250bea +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106   3
>
>   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x000000010915eff3
>   _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 176  4   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x0000000109171bc3
>   _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph8_ConnectEP19AVAudioNodeImplBaseS1_jjP13AVAudioFormat
>   + 1281    5   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x0000000109174df0 _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 322    6   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00000001091a7a71
>   _ZN17AVAudioEngineImpl7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 301  7   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00000001091a7ad8
>   -[AVAudioEngine connect:to:format:] + 83  8   AudioKit                            0x00000001037a611b
>   _TTSf4n_d___TZFC8AudioKit8AudioKits6outputGSqCS_6AKNode_ + 267    9   GitarTelleri                        0x000000010362c234
>   *TFC12GitarTelleri18GameViewController13viewDidAppearfSbT* + 196  10  GitarTelleri                        0x000000010362c341
>   *TToFC12GitarTelleri18GameViewController13viewDidAppearfSbT* + 49     11  UIKit                               0x0000000104df7335
>   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 830    12  UIKit                               0x0000000104e30589 -[UINavigationController viewDidAppear:] + 207   13 
>   UIKit                               0x0000000104df7335
>   -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 830    14  UIKit                               0x0000000104df7cb8 -[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 262
>     15  UIKit                               0x0000000104dc208a
>   -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 827    16  UIKit                               0x0000000104f9f38f -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController
>   transitionDidFinish:] + 42    17  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000104dc57c1 __56-[UIPresentationController
>   runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183    18  UIKit
>
>   0x00000001056844c8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext
>   completeTransition:] + 101    19  UIKit
>
>   0x0000000104dbef77 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] +
>   252   20  UIKit                               0x0000000104dbec88
>   -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1344    21  UIKit                               0x0000000104dc13f4 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] +
>   104   22  UIKit                               0x0000000104ce47ff
>   -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 241  23  UIKit                               0x0000000104ce4bae
>   -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80   24  QuartzCore                          0x0000000107d7d3c8
>   _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308    25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000108c773eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8     26  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x0000000108c5f1ef _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738   27 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001041aa0f9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010416bb99 __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2073    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010416b0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488   30  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010a189ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  31  UIKit
>   0x0000000104c56f09 UIApplicationMain + 171    32  GitarTelleri
>   0x0000000103630372 main + 114     33  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000108cab92d start + 1  34  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Should I change something in AppDelegate.swift or should I clean something when BackButton is clicked?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your audio, not your view controller

Comment: how do you implement the controllers? Is it in a NavigationCoontroller? Storyboard? Or hard in the AppDelegate?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon you are right, the problem is with the audio. I was using AudioKit framework and I was starting AudioKit framework "using AudioKit.start()"  when GameViewController is played, but it was not stopping when my program passes to another viewcontroller, so I have added a condition which stops the AudioKit framework when the program passes to another viewcontroller. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

check your back button have AudioKit.stop()

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! It is great that you are already contributing to the site, thank you for that. This question did not have an accepted answer, however, in the comments you can already see that it was resolved by the user who asked the question. In cases like this it is preferred to give an answer that is elaborate, summarizes the issue and can provide value to those who visit this question in the future. Your answer seems to be right, however, it does not add much value to this Q&A - but with being more elaborate you could do so!